# How to hide (zip)files from users or make them mutable

Tags: c#, windows

We are trying to make sure that our users can't under any circumstances alter the files in any way.

Is there a way to prevent normal non-admin users from interacting with files that my application need to interact with?

Say there are N amount of files that my application interact with. Once the application get a reference for these files then users should not be able to interact with them. Right now I am making a copy of the files and hide them under appdata in my applications folder.

This works for the normal Joe, who is just doing his job and working hard as he will never try to look for trouble down there, but the bored Adam will probably go and play hacker when nothing special happens.

The files are storred on the local computer until they are sent, with another application, to a remote database. The time between the files first interaction with my application and the event of being transferred to the database can range from seconds to weeks.

I have a local database on the computer, but I can not store the files there because there can be N amount files that needs to be transferred and some other data needs to be stored in the database as well. I believe the max capacity of the database is 4 GB, which would make it impossible to store the data.

The computer is also not under my supervision, so I am not allowed to change OS settings, and I can't store the data remotely either, because if I could then it would be sent to the remote server.

My current solution hack solution would be to hold the file in memory (so it can't be changed durring the process) create a hash of it, which I will store in the database, and then make X amount of copies that I will spread out in different parts of the computer. This way Adam needs to touch more than one file, which are all in a non-disclossed location, to be able to sabotage everything. This would also require him to search in a couple of folders to find the files, which would require work and which Adam will probably try to avoid.

The problem here is that I don't really know what kind of sociopathic maniac Adam is, so even by going this far would still be throwing die with god.

That's why I am wondering if there are places where Adam can't touch or ways to hide/lock the files in a way so that Adam can't alter och destroy them?

Comment: What type of application are you developing (UWP, Winforms, WPF etc)? What versions of Windows are you targeting? Loosely only tampering could be detected, encryption and inclusion of hash signatures are the way forward.

Comment: Can't remember the exact kind, but some applications deployed through the microsoft store can access a secure storage, that only they, through their package identity can access. The user will get an access denied from the system, and even as an administrator it is non-trivial to alter the files. Easiest examples coming to mind are games distributed through the microsoft store.

Comment: Can't you just encrypt / decrypt the file? If you can't decrypt it correctly, you'll know someone has changed it.

Comment: @ChrisBD Windows application that is targeted towards windows 7, (maybe earlier as we have some stations running lower versions of the software on an XP OS, but the currently it is probably only goes as low as windows 7) to windows 10. Yes, that solves tampering, but not the ability to delete files sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent normal non-admin users from interacting with files that my application need to interact with?

Programs run in the context of the user that starts them. If your user is not able to edit a file, your program won't be able to edit it, either. If your program is able to edit the file, your users WILL ultimately have that ability. **There is no separating the two.**

As an example, zip files also support password protection. So you *could* put everything in a password-protected zip file, where the password is embedded/obfuscated in your application and not known to the user. In this case, it will be extremely difficult for the user to open the zip file in the normal way. But even then, *the user will still able to tamper with the file via a text editor.* They may not come out with anything useful, but they did still modify the file.

The one thing you can do is **detect** the tampering. You can compute and save a hash value for your files, and check the contents of the file match the saved hash.

One other option you may have is using multiple databases. I don't know what kind of database you have that's giving you a 4 GB limit, but if it's something file-based like sqlite there's no reason not to have multiple files. Keep in mind, though, the user still has the ability to tamper with these files in a text editor. If it's SQL Server Express, the version with the 4 GB limit has been end-of-life and *fully-unsupported* for several years *and should not be used!* Newer releases of Express are still free and now offer a 10 GB limit, and also allow you to have *multiple databases* with a 10 GB limit each.

Comment: Note that a sufficiently clever attacker can update the hash in the local database to match their modifications.  Or just attack the client program and inject the altered payload into the client itself, before it calculates the hash. Even uploading the hash to a server isn't good enough, because the attacker can just patch the program so it ignores the hash mismatch.